# How can I build a website with template and rest api for mobile app in Django

Tags: django

I want to build a project with Django framework, it includes website and mobile app, website is built based on Django template, and mobile app needs rest api. How can I do it with only one copy of source code?

In other words, can I create one project, in which there are several django apps, it supports returning both rendering template and json for mobile app?

I know we can use Angular JS in website, then both website and mobile app access rest api build with Django-Rest-Framework. But I have no idea about Angular JS and there is no time for me to learn it.

Please help.

Comment: Why my question is downvote? Is it unclear, without any search, or anything else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy to achieve if you leverage the power of HTTP headers, specifically speaking the "Content-Type" header
([HTTP 1.1 headers specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17))

The way I personally use it is something like this:

```
def my_view_name(request):

    if 'CONTENT_TYPE' in request.META and \
        request.META['CONTENT_TYPE'] == 'application/json':
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps({"foo":"bar"}), 
                content_type='application/json'
            )
    else:
        return render_to_response(
            'sometemplate.html', context
        )
```

The code above is django-specific.

It allows you to control what kind of response the server doles out, based out what the client passes in. It can detect that a JSON response is needed by checking the `Content-Type` header.
Just ensure your mobile app makes its HTTP requests with the `Content-Type`header set to `application/json`

Hope that's what you wanted.

Comment: That is what I want, and I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one project. Have the same Model, but have different views for website and REST-api.

Answer (score 1):

You can build one Common Backend to serve your data.

And you can do this without having a Django-rest-Framework(without having to use angular).
You are just going call the url of the backend.

For eg.,. lets say backend code is running at 127.0.0.1/8000, and you need to get a user's details, you are just going to call url 127.0.0.1:8000/get_user_details/ from mobile app or any other front end.

And please make a habit of forming/arranging data written in a different function so that it is reusable by both the Mobile app and the website.(plz see below)

```
###  For browser website written in DJANGO (served in template by django):
def user_details_page(request):
    get_user_details(someid)    #### returns json of user details
    render in template

#### And for the mobile App you could use **get_user_details(someid)** just to get json data.

def get_user_details(someid):
   ###do watever
   return json ## of user details
```

And you can also use Django Rest Framework(without having to use angular), it gives you a lot of stability.

Or you can setup a entire new backend in Django Framework to serve data for mobile App.

Comment: for `render in template` do you means bind json to html elements in my template?

Comment: For 'render in template' I meant for the Actual Browser Website. Yes, you can bind the json in template for showing on browser.

Comment: Same backend for Mobile App & broswer web app. You can make the browser front end more mobile responsive(mobile browser). But I dont think you can have same front end for MOBILE APP.